# codeigniter display images from directory

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I'm trying through a function display in browser all the images i have in a directory of my codeigniter code, and so i'm using the following code:

```
$imgdir = 'upload/'; //Pick your folder
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif'); //Allowed types of files
$dimg = opendir($imgdir);//Open directory
while($imgfile = readdir($dimg))
{

if( in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types) OR
in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-4)),$allowed_types) )
/*If the file is an image add it to the array*/
{$a_img[] = $imgfile;}
}
echo "<ul>";

$totimg = count($a_img);  //The total count of all the images
//Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='http://localhost/code/'" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>"; echo $imgdir . $a_img[$x];} 
echo "<li><img src='http://localhost/code/upload/corrosivo.jpg' /></li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

What i don't get it is why i get broken image boxes in browser in the:

```
echo "<li><img src='http://localhost/code/'" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>"; echo $imgdir . $a_img[$x];}
```

and with:

```
echo "<li><img src='http://localhost/code/upload/corrosivo.jpg' /></li>";
```

the image is successful displayed.

I already verify the vars and they have the right content.

Comment: You're prematurely closing your src attribute on your img tag.
<img src='[http://localhost/code/](http://localhost/code/)'

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, it really was that :D